# React : Pass function to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to pass a function to my child component. For each child component when the user click on them, the onclick function will be call. This onclick function is written into the parent component.

Parent component:

```
class AgentsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    const { agents } = this.props;

    ...

    var agentsNodes = agents.map(function(agent, i) {
      if(agent.id_intervention == "") {
        return (
          <Agent agent={agent} key={i} ticket={t} id={row_names} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
        );
      }
    });
    return (
      <div id="agents">
        <div className="agents-title">
          <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        {agentsNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child component:

```
class Agent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { agent, t } = this.props;

    return (
      <Link to='/' onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        ...
      </Link>
    );
  }
}
```

At this line : `<Agent agent={agent} key={i} ticket={t} id={row_names} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />`

It say that handleClick is not defined ...
How can I sovle this problem ?

Thank's for your answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to bind Agents to AgentsList:
Here's a quick example with your code, I had to get rid of some stuff, but you get the idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/vhuumox0/19/

```
var agentsNodes = agents.map(function(agent, i) {
  if(agent.id_intervention == "") {
    return (
      <Agent agent={agent} key={i} ticket={t} id={row_names} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
    );
  }
}, this); // here
```

Comment: You may also use `onClick={() => this.handleClick()}`.

Comment: @ZhenyangHua actually this is a better approach so you don't need to use `bind` anymore.

Comment: what if there are like 8 functions

Comment: then you pass each on in individually

Comment: @ZhenyangHua how do you pass event with that way (parameter)?

Comment: @AmelSalibasic `onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}`

Comment: @Downhillski Wouldn't `onClick={() => this.handleClick()}` (arrow function) or using bind break the reference check mechanism of React since they always create new functions?