# React function says "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on breaking up a little react app into smaller components. Before separating code everything worked as planned. I now am trying to call a function `onChange` that calls a function and then that calls a function as a `prop`. I am binding the function like this `this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);` but I still cannot figure out what I am missing. I tried a recent post on here ([React : Pass function to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636259/react-pass-function-to-child-component)) but the error still remains. Any help is great.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
class Weather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      city: '',
      details: []
    };

    this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
  }

  updateInputValue(e) {
    this.setState({
      city: e.target.value
    });
    console.log('hit')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.container + ' ' + style.bodyText}>
        <WeatherForm
          updateInput={this.updateInputValue}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class WeatherForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this); 
  }

  updateInput(e) {
    this.props.updateInputValue(e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.weatherForm}>
        <form action='/' method='GET'>
          <input ref='city' value={this.props.inputValue} onChange={e => this.updateInput(e)} type='text' placeholder='Search city' />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So when I type one character in the input, instead of the console logging `hit`, it says `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.updateInputValue is not a function`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps it should be just `this.updateInputValue(e)` and not `this.props.updateInputValue(e)`.

Comment: Simple, first determine what `this.props` is using `console.log`. Once that's done you'll see your mistake by yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be

```
<WeatherForm
          updateInputValue={this.updateInputValue}
        />
```

**Common related problem:**

The same "is not a function" error can also be caused by mis-using the props, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663809/react-typeerror-x-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 6):

Your child component only has the prop of `updateInput` as a method and you're calling `this.props.updateInputValue()` in child component. Try to call them the same names.

You're also calling `this.props.inputValue` in the child component when you're not passing `inputValue` into your child component as a props.

What I would do to simplify the code and possible avoid mistakes like this in the future is to directly call `this.props.updateInputValue` in onChange event like this：`onChange={e => this.props.updateInputValue(e)}`
You then save the work of binding another component method in constructor. It'll also make your unit testing easier but that's another discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The `this.props.inputValue` is the next problem up on the task list. Thanks for the explanation there also. At times the `prop` stuff makes me cross-eyed.

Answer (score -1):

**If you are using React Hooks than this can be helpful answer.** `note: I am using react 18`

If your set is throwing this error:
[image]

**Solution:**

You must not be defining your setTitle properly, or you must be restructing the state in wrong way.

- `const {title, setTitle} = useState("");` is wrong
- `const [title, setTitle] = useState("");` is correct

Code Sample:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";


export default () => {
    const {title, setTitle} = useState("");

    const onSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); 

        const createdId = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/posts", {
            "title": title
        });

        setTitle("");
    };

    const handleTextChange = (event) => {        
        setTitle(event.target.value)
    }

    return <div>
        <form>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label> Title </label>
                <input value={title} onChange={handleTextChange} className="form-control"></input>
            </div>
            <div className="btn btn-primary" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                Submit
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>;
};
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541