# React TypeError: x is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I call the function 'booksRefresh()' from the parent in the child component, but I get the error:

> TypeError: booksRefresh is not a function

I don't know why, because 'booksRefresh' is a function. Can someone help me explain why this error occurs?

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Redirect} from "react-router";
import {addBook} from "../api/api";
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";

const AddBookForm = (booksRefresh) => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState();
    const [description, setDescription] = useState();
    const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

    const postRequestHandler = () => {
        addBook(title, description);
        booksRefresh();
    }
...
 return (
        ...
            <Button type="submit" onClick={postRequestHandler} variant="outline-success">Add</Button>
        </div>
    )
```

Parent:

```
function App({history}) {
  ...
    const [changeInBooks, setChangeInBooks] = useState(0)

    const booksRefresh = () => {
        let incrementChangeInBook = changeInBooks + 1;
        setChangeInBooks(incrementChangeInBook)
    }
return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                ...
                            <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={() => history.push("/new-book")}>
                                {ADD_BOOK}</Button>
                ...
            </header>
            <Switch>
                ...
                <Route path="/new-book" exact render={() =>
                    <AddBookForm
                        booksRefresh={booksRefresh}/>
                }/>
               ...
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: `const AddBookForm = ({ booksRefresh })` you have to spread the props.

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan - That's not spread, it's destructuring.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The argument a React function component receives is its **props**, which is an object with named properties for each of the properties. So your `AddBookForm`'s parameter shouldn't be `booksRefresh`, but (by convention) `props`, and then you use it via `props.booksRefresh()`:

```
const AddBookForm = (props) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
    const [title, setTitle] = useState();
    const [description, setDescription] = useState();
    const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

    const postRequestHandler = () => {
        addBook(title, description);
        props.booksRefresh();
// −−−−−^^^^^^
    }

    // ...
```

Or if it's the only prop, you can use destructuring [as adiga shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59663851/157247):

```
const AddBookForm = ({booksRefresh}) => {
```

Answer (score 4):

The *props* parameter is an object with a property called `booksRefresh` inside it.

Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the property

```
const AddBookForm = ({ booksRefresh }) => {

}
```

You are already doing it to get `history` in the `App` component

Answer (score 4):

```
const AddBookForm = ({booksRefresh}) => {
        const [title, setTitle] = useState();
        const [description, setDescription] = useState();
        const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

        const postRequestHandler = () => {
            addBook(title, description);
            booksRefresh();
        }
```

try this
i hope it works

because of props.booksRefresh is a function

Answer (score 3):

Because first argument of functional component is props

```
function Component(props) {
}
```

You have to retrieve prop by name

```
function Component(props) {
 const prop = props.propName
}
```

Or using destructuring

```
function Component({propName) {
}
```