# How to call a method from different component in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a snack setup:

https://snack.expo.io/@sj458147/view-not-scrolling

when you click show modal -> Click next button the View horizontally scrolls (animated), which then displays an image carousel. Now when you click an image, the View should horizontally scroll again but I get the error undefined is not an object. The error lies within the file:

SliderEntry.js

```
select = () => {
this.MyScrollView.current.moveToPage(3);
};
```

any help resolving the issue would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have `MyScrollView` ref in `ShowModal`. There are 2 ways:

- Not recommend: Pass `MyScrollView` ref as props to Slider, then pass to SliderEntry
- Recommend: create a callback as props in `SliderEntry`. Callback to `Slider`, then callback to `ShowModal`

Answer (score 0):

Pass your function in props to other components and then access these functions from your another component.

You can find the answer here

[React : Pass function to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636259/react-pass-function-to-child-component)